# Stacking FlowLayout panels in a BorderLayout panel causes all but the SOUTH panel to disappear?

Tags: java, swing

I have an application in which I'm trying to simply stack two `FlowLayout` panels on top of each other inside of a `BorderLayout` panel. However, when I do it neither of the panels are visible.

Before I tried stacking those panels the form looks like this:

[image: Before Stacking]

but after stacking them it looks like this:

[image: After Stacking]

When using the SSCCE, the line that causes the problem is this one:

```
pane.add(textAreaPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

so if you comment that line out the form will at least show the first panel.

## SSCCE

#### TutoringCalculator

```
package tutoringcalculator;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TutoringCalculator extends JFrame {
    FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);

    public TutoringCalculator(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void addComponentsToPane(final Container pane) {
        final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel.setLayout(layout);
        final JPanel textAreaPanel = new JPanel();
        textAreaPanel.setLayout(layout);
        final JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

        contentPanel.add(new JLabel("Session Minutes:"));

        JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);
        txt.setName("sessionMinutes");

        txt.addFocusListener(new DecimalFieldFocusListener(new IValidDecimalValue() {
            @Override
            public boolean callback(String val) {
                return ApplicationState.getInstance().setCurrentSessionMinutes(val);
            }
        }));
        contentPanel.add(txt);

        // setup the default border
        ApplicationState.getInstance().setDefaultTextFieldBorder(txt.getBorder());

        contentPanel.add(new JLabel("Earnings:"));

        txt = new JTextField(10);
        txt.setName("earnings");

        txt.addFocusListener(new DecimalFieldFocusListener(new IValidDecimalValue() {
            @Override
            public boolean callback(String val) {
                return ApplicationState.getInstance().setCurrentEarnings(val);
            }
        }));
        contentPanel.add(txt);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Enter");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String result = ApplicationState.getInstance().acceptEarnings();
                if (result != null) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result, "Error Entering Earnings", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The session minutes and earnings were accepted.", "Success!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                    JTextField sessionMinutes = (JTextField)contentPanel.getComponent(1);
                    sessionMinutes.setText("");

                    JTextField earnings = (JTextField)contentPanel.getComponent(3);
                    earnings.setText("");

                    sessionMinutes.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
        contentPanel.add(btn);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textAreaPanel.add(textArea);

        btn = new JButton("Run Report");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        buttons.add(btn);

        btn = new JButton("Quit");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        buttons.add(btn);

        pane.add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(textAreaPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        TutoringCalculator frame = new TutoringCalculator("Tutoring Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        //Set up the content pane.
        frame.addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        //Display the window.
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
        try {
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatchi thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### ApplicationState

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package tutoringcalculator;

import javax.swing.border.Border;

/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
final public class ApplicationState {
    private static ApplicationState instance = new ApplicationState();
    public static ApplicationState getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private ApplicationState() {

    }

    private Border defaultTextFieldBorder;
    public Border getDefaultTextFieldBorder() {
        return defaultTextFieldBorder;
    }
    public void setDefaultTextFieldBorder(Border b) {
        defaultTextFieldBorder = b;
    }

    private double currentSessionMinutes;
    private boolean isValidSessionMinutes;
    public boolean setCurrentSessionMinutes(String text) {
        isValidSessionMinutes = false;
        try {
            currentSessionMinutes = Double.parseDouble(text);
            isValidSessionMinutes = true;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private double currentEarnings;
    private boolean isValidCurrentEarnings;
    public boolean setCurrentEarnings(String text) {
        isValidCurrentEarnings = false;
        try {
            currentEarnings = Double.parseDouble(text);
            isValidCurrentEarnings = true;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public String acceptEarnings() {
        if (!(isValidSessionMinutes && isValidCurrentEarnings)) {
            return "Please enter valid session minutes and current earnings.";
        }

        addEarnings(currentSessionMinutes, currentEarnings);

        return null;
    }

    private double[][] earningsArray = new double[100][2];
    private int newRowIndex = 0;
    private void addEarnings(double sessionMinutes, double earnings) {
        earningsArray[newRowIndex][0] = sessionMinutes;
        earningsArray[newRowIndex][1] = earnings;
        newRowIndex++;
    }
}
```

#### DecimalFieldFocusListener

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package tutoringcalculator;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
public class DecimalFieldFocusListener implements FocusListener {
    private IValidDecimalValue _callback;

    public DecimalFieldFocusListener(IValidDecimalValue callback) {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        JTextField txt = (JTextField)e.getSource();
        if (!_callback.callback(txt.getText())) {
            txt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, Color.red));
        }
        else {
            txt.setBorder(ApplicationState.getInstance().getDefaultTextFieldBorder());
            txt.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
    }
}
```

#### IValidDecimalValue

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package tutoringcalculator;

/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
public interface IValidDecimalValue {
    boolean callback(String val);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one component can appear at the `BorderLayout.CENTER` location. Therefore when

```
pane.add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
pane.add(textAreaPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

is called, `textAreaPanel` effectively displaces `contentPanel`. Instead you can place `contentPanel` in the `NORTH` location:

```
pane.add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot. I'm ***very*** new to Java. I've been building .NET applications for 13 years, and honestly, the only thing I'm **really** struggling with in Java is the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Only one component may be in each location. When you put two panels in at `BorderLayout.CENTER` it's like placing one on top of the other. If you would like to stack components on top of each other, you can use the BorderLayout Manager. It allows components to be stacked along the X-axis or the Y-axis of a container. You can implement it this way:

```
pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        pane.add(contentPanel);
        pane.add(textAreaPanel);
        pane.add(buttons);
```